# Trying to transfer data over from a csv into a struct and its overwriting the data thats been put in, In C, by the end every spot is the same as last

Tags: arrays, c, csv, cs50

Im trying to transfer data over from a csv that has 30 lines and 3 pieces of data on each line. The name of x crime, the minimum sentence in months, and the maximum sentence in months. When I iterate the first time around it will take crime[i].crime_name and set it to the first crime, set the sentence correctly, and move on to the next. But the second time it loops it will overrwrite the crime[0].crime_name and replace it with the information from crime[1].crime_name . It does this all the way until the loop is finished and all 30 spots have the same information. Heres my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>


typedef struct
{
    string crime_name;
    int minsent;
    int maxsent;
}
crimes;

crimes crime[30];


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

 FILE* fp = fopen("crimes.csv", "r");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    return 1;
}
 else{

     char buffer[1024];

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    while (fgets(buffer,1024, fp))
        {

        // Splitting the data

        column = 0;

        int i = row;
       char* value = strtok(buffer, ",");
        
        char* values = malloc(50);
        strcpy(values, value);

            // Column 1
            if (column == 0)
            {
               crime[i].crime_name = values;
            //   printf("%s", crime[row].crime_name);
               column++;
               value = strtok(NULL, ",");
               strcpy(values, value);

            }

            // Column 2
            if (column == 1)
            {
                int min = atoi(values);
                value = strtok(NULL, ",");
                crime[i].minsent = min;
                column++;
                strcpy(values, value);

            }

            // Column 3
            if (column == 2)
            {
                int max = atoi(values);
                value = strtok(NULL, ",");
                crime[i].maxsent = max;
                column++;
              
            }
             row++;
             free (values);
        }

}

  string input = get_string("\nInput the name of the crime, or use list to see a list of the possible crimes:");



 FILE *pointer_list = fopen("list.csv" , "r");

string list = "list";

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{

  printf("\n");
  if(strcmp(input, list) == 0 )
    {
        char c = fgetc(pointer_list);

        while(c != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(pointer_list);
    }

        printf("\n");
        return 0;

    }
       printf("The crime you chose is %s", crime[i].crime_name);

    if (strcmp(input, crime[i].crime_name) == 0 )
    {
        printf("The crime you chose is %s", crime[i].crime_name);
        printf("\t The minimumm sentence for this crime is %i", crime[i].minsent);
        printf("\t The maximum sentence for this crime is %i", crime[i].maxsent);
    }



    if (strcmp(input, list) == 1 || strcmp(input, crime[i].crime_name) == 1)
    {

        printf("Syntax error, try again");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

    }
```

And heres the csv,

```
assault and battery , 0 , 12
aggravated assault , 0 , 12
domestic violence , 0 , 2
domestic battery , 0 , 12
illegal entry , 0 , 24
child abuse, 0 , 60
contributing to the delinquency of a minor , 0 , 3
insurance fraud , 0 , 48
1st degree murder , 240 , 960 
2nd degree murder , 180 , 960
3rd degree murder , 120 , 180
manslaughter , 10 , 180
arson , 12 , 240
money laundering , 0 , 240
disorderly conduct , 0 , 3
stalking , 0 , 12
prostitution , 0 , 60
Fraud , 0 , 240f
hit and run , 0 , 180
DUI , 1 , 60
Driving Under Influence , 1 , 60
selling alcohol to a minor , 0 , 12
public intoxication , 0 , 3
credit card fraud , 12 , 60
Retail Fraud , 0 , 60
Larceny , 0 , 60
Shoplifting , 0 , 12
Reckless driving , 0 , 3
Driving with suspended license , 0 , 3
indecent exposure , 0 ,  12
```

Comment: You have to make a copy of the input line, and you do, but you can't free it before you've finished with it.

Comment: What version of C are you using? There's no "string" definition in any standard C that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

The line `crime[i].crime_name = values;` **does not** copy the text in `values` to `crime[i].crime_name`. Rather, it copies the memory address of `values`.

Currently when `values` is reassigned to the next crime name, it changes what's in every `crime_name` that's already been assigned the address of `values`

To avoid this, you need to make a hard copy using something such as strcpy, which I see you already know how to use ;)